# How to multiply 1000 prime numbers in Java

Tags: java, multiplication

I need to multiply around 1000 prime numbers in Java. 
For example 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19*....... Is it possible? 
I tried with below one:

```
    BigInteger resultBig = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    int n = 0;
    long result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
          {
         n = Prime(i);
         result = result * n;
         resultBig = new BigInteger(Integer.toString((int) result));
           }
```

Comment: Please post `Prime`, and whatever other code we would need to reproduce the issue. Also, tell us **how** it isn't working.

Comment: David--if the long overflows, it wont matter if its the right size for the BigInteger. You need to work directly with the biginteger.

Comment: int isn't big enough

Comment: @Frisch, to post as prime I need to have 15 reputations which I don't have right now as I am new with stackoverflow.

Comment: @David He means include the `Prime` method in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, you must do the math using `BigInteger`.

```
final int[] primes = {
        2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29,
        // list abbreviated for clarity
        7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919
};

BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(primes[i]));
System.out.println(result);
```

Using the full list of 1000 primes found [here](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt), the result is:

```
678629608419755514953266004896957820972161078160377361970324401521111792080121479864721936071815069425907219215791646774510151130705671056416094404541167439287735488353736963531288441938981088407654256240451529081607242659988552012480001287133802278572298314458227654950008738955663072953766341488209509227159933381319371567666804963833249523370831655778314080604712246344649628072459805028063160913071005795183295590443375991860551286230065601580359306757988823124262933259305966372664091680948986620887898883461227980556352852601733860114246410887151983493540958775872577571329277597701163671587052591794386970584444752423596023268793021595936555282977008138833858707329536639661377014042325817639809356799596347944462538427778375525904007169834445567450156949173690701738594584875536885957881452438269676946038980597530032671949818526703398270502591574889228837327819994695664173214894557366363343168494592437205324652573516528943874382178600874878024643322031797588414862315122048846223291257900756812820806739795819803783834366449110996030165071920678407750230118672657378102915524688059208755108467225277065866103666795739208709483959119145497860116133180335757702319385020561042517429031288526721801002679092058170909635701703382390753126302005323612316630558515594616479515096004453718500060291836932140612551722161051067379805065002788004096547708243964735215852734827632098700684466036892770059458754742495711074949314613079781545359495019757827538184361308856825999513366660884541936335491466045305322353749545362962683762333460252556042583248154845846566948014188971651057314058851019340282646752239847232045463969939303431371658607220786663205842510175297602195433569758123945251755043878718459161595137019904240640962465899496512410906852088532419874383895656303779315512987369934711061777117329635461569528504994783413643047392160871963795694958724055597996525917454740621526108635321204763824742430011606570436994644169759611263012712375861911682673548369764923418748711813157811279361700331599397588282864147719911156923709896847720603482450047076226728760035577410722701184878333100234780537897462936378382079055966277885316116887834607362114802378706815302650083359076798475953780285866955566883261644281750278358349579977889429105626865087038835977930842352223971442123281019745568694318200865586150762549114357677130353514342849892002965601064686292493671204318349298134598116662388818407027989992498970986262856712232401426575229549744739851333516937170071337085705197690437625282926914858257689908846227286051735284322402597283976180484905838486513162987381659809287870592690902387482033879184700359561190209417618607868793293476867624464497838299321267571049753373623085351455438610076341961842557148160442782839736179329056237366708383637405663196770746783100179128651460773512143616414356080816160456447832856222804164147618891013658880373227849181446498052320436905124576367614898030410445386643656246089772967461562154147355201124738052009172637452710027640262529821855681129322547617443299372089380860873141895162966481252930360380537684913059090577224188204179681342669502124011214018434733385892140553307905100266308832521127607403573729242486985024795253305646999864066282626291530104297235324933472771821035277094700384260778312268190937365143307612108901729316774669077441981239149913617114331308200242717771235228048768133852203532299832810943137983635951570
```

**Very Big Number:** 3393 digits long.
Definitely larger than either `int` (<10 digits) or `long` (<19 digits) could manage.